# Redirection to User Profile After Login in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, authentication

I'm trying to get my web app to redirect to the user's profile after they login. I'm fairly new to this language, but from what I understand, I want to call `View(~/Views/Manage/Index.cshtml", user)` from the AccountController.cs on a successful login where `user` is of type IndexViewModel.

I'm not sure exactly what to call to get this to work. I was following [this](http://nimblegecko.com/how-to-avoid-and-fix-nullreferenceexceptions-in-asp-net-mvc/) tutorial and it helped me solve the null exception, but I don't know how to get the model for the user that is currently logged in. Can someone tell me what I may be looking for, or is there a better way to achieve this goal? I've looked all over, and can't seem to find what I need.

I'm using the default ASP.NET template which takes a LoginViewModel as a parameter to the login function so I'm thinking I might be able to pull it from there?

Edit: Code that authenticates:

```
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToAction("Index");//Been playing with this line
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use RedirctToAction("Index","user") instead of view(). Is that what you want to ask?

Comment: ...maybe. I still don't know what "user" would need to be.

Comment: Once the user is successfully authenticated, you should use `RedirectToAction` to redirect user to the action which will show profile view. In that action you should build the ViewModel which you need to pass to the view. Can you share the code which authenticates the user for the username and password user has entered?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I threw it in the OP. PasswordSigninAsync seems like a library function. Isn't there a way to do like "GetLoggedInUser()" without having to build the ViewModel manually?

Comment: @jake.toString There is no such method. Different applications have different requirement of details about the logged in user. What you can do is  access Controller's `User.Identity` property which gives you the basic minimal information about the logged in user such as UserName and UserId.

Comment: Hey @manika if you wanna post your comment as an answer, I'll select it. I ended up using `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage", routeValues: null);` but thanks to everyone for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedirectToAction construct a redirect url to a specific action/controller in your application and use the route table to generate the correct URL. RedirectToAction cause the browser to receive a 302 redirect within your application and gives you an easier way to work with your route table. In your given case, use RedirctToAction("Index","user") instead of view(). For more information you can go through to this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a model which exposes your user profile object, this model would then be defined at the top of your view.

Comment: The model is defined at the top of the view:

`@model OrderAnyday.Models.IndexViewModel`

Am I thinking of it wrong to think of this as a "class" and then I need an object of this "class" for the current user?

Comment: No, you're right, your model reference at the top of the view points to your viewmodel class, typically which would be created by a factory/helper ( ie keep your controller as uncluttered as possible).

Comment: Okay. Can you maybe post an example of what that might look like? Like what would creating the object look like? Would I do it within the function in the Controller?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me, I'm on phone, but essentially;

Factory class eg UserModelFactory
Method.eg CreateModel

This method instantiates the model with the required values.

Ideally use a DI framework (eg AutoFac, Ninject) to pass in any constructor arguments (defined by their interface not concrete types), this makes your factory easily tested and mockable.